# Combine two graphs by an axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm studing with datasets and represent variables. I tried with this dataset https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/automobile. I want to represent the `city-mpg` and `highway-mpg` vs `num-of-cylinders`. My code in R

```
library(ggplot2)
data <- read.csv('http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/autos/imports-85.data', header=F, sep = "," ,dec = ".",
                 colClasses = c('factor','numeric','factor','factor','factor','factor','factor','factor','factor',
                                'numeric','numeric','numeric','numeric','numeric','factor','factor','numeric',
                                'factor','numeric','numeric','numeric','numeric','numeric','numeric',
                                'numeric','numeric'), na.strings = "?")

colnames(data) <- c("symboling", "normalized-losses","make","fuel-type","aspiration",
                 "num-of-doors","body-style","drive-wheels","engine-location","wheel-base","length",
                 "width","height","curb-weight","engine-type","num-of-cylinders","engine-size","fuel-system",
                 "bore","stroke","compression-ratio","horsepower","peak-rpm","city-mpg","highway-mpg","price")
summary(data)

data$`num-of-cylinders` <- as.character(data$`num-of-cylinders`)
data$`num-of-cylinders`[which(data$`num-of-cylinders` == "two")] <- "2"
data$`num-of-cylinders`[which(data$`num-of-cylinders` == "three")] <- "3"
data$`num-of-cylinders`[which(data$`num-of-cylinders` == "four")] <- "4"
data$`num-of-cylinders`[which(data$`num-of-cylinders` == "five")] <- "5"
data$`num-of-cylinders`[which(data$`num-of-cylinders` == "six")] <- "6"
data$`num-of-cylinders`[which(data$`num-of-cylinders` == "eight")] <- "8"
data$`num-of-cylinders`[which(data$`num-of-cylinders` == "twelve")] <- "12"
data$`num-of-cylinders` <- as.numeric(data$`num-of-cylinders`)
data$`num-of-cylinders` <- as.factor(data$`num-of-cylinders`)

ggplot(data = data, aes(x = `num-of-cylinders`, y = `city-mpg`)) +
      geom_boxplot() +
      xlab('Number of Cylinders') +
      ylab('MPG') +
      ggtitle('MPG Comparison by Number of Cylinders') 

ggplot(data = data, aes(x = `num-of-cylinders`, y = `highway-mpg`)) +
      geom_boxplot() +
      xlab('Number of Cylinders') +
      ylab('MPG') +
      ggtitle('MPG Comparison by Number of Cylinders')
```

I can represent the boxplot separately but there is a way to have the same `y` axis (`city-mpg` and `highway-mpg`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd first make a suggestion: give columns names using underscores (_) instead of hyphens (-), because you can call `data$city_mpg` but you can't call `data$city-mpg`.

Second, `ggplot` generally expects data in a long format, not a wide one. Think about what you're trying to do: compare mpg to number of cylinders, grouped by condition (city vs highway). Reshape it into a long format and treat city vs highway as a variable on which you can map color or split into facets.

Two options of what you can add to your code are below, one using colors and one using facets.

```r
data_long <- tidyr::gather(data, key = measure, value = mpg, `city-mpg`, `highway-mpg`)

ggplot(data_long, aes(x = `num-of-cylinders`, y = mpg, color = measure)) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    xlab('Number of Cylinders') +
    ylab('MPG') +
    ggtitle('MPG Comparison by Number of Cylinders and Road Type')
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(data_long, aes(x = `num-of-cylinders`, y = mpg)) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    xlab('Number of Cylinders') +
    ylab('MPG') +
    ggtitle('MPG Comparison by Number of Cylinders and Road Type') +
    facet_wrap(~measure)
```

[image]

Created on 2018-04-10 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 1):

Like most analytical processes, ggplot works best with long data. Simply stack the *city_mpg* subset on top of *highway_mpg* subset with indicators for city and highway. Below uses *underscores* for column names and not hyphens.

```
# RBIND TWO DATAFRAME SUBSETS (RENAMING W/ setNames AND ADDING NEW COLUMN W/ transform)
long_data <- rbind(transform(setNames(data[c("num_of_cylinders", "city_mpg")],
                                      c("num_of_cylinders", "mpg")), mile_type = "city"),
                   transform(setNames(data[c("num_of_cylinders", "highway_mpg")],
                                      c("num_of_cylinders", "mpg")), mile_type = "highway"))

# PLOT LONG DATA
ggplot(data = long_data, aes(x = num_of_cylinders, y = mpg, colour=mile_type)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  xlab('Number of Cylinders') +
  ylab('MPG') +
  ggtitle('MPG Comparison by Number of Cylinders')
```

[image: Plot Output]